# How to add "Bearer" another route headers after user logged in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm new to programming and I'm currently working on a small project.

I'm trying to implement some authorization using JWT.
I've watched a few videos online and found that most people have the "Bearer" + access token in their headers.

I've gone through a few posts and I found that I needed to add the authorization "Bearer" myself but I'm not quite sure how to get there.

Can I please get some help?

Here are some of my code

Login

```
 if(response){
            if(await bcrypt.compare(loginPW, response.password)){
                const accessToken = jwt.sign({
                    email: response.email
                },jwtSecret)
                res.json({status: 'ok', accessToken: accessToken})
            }else{
                return res.json({status: 'error', error:'Invalid Credentials'})
            }
        }
```

Post request

```
const result = await fetch('/',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            loginEmail, loginPassword, reqType
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

just add Authorization header with your token to request

```js
const result = await fetch('/',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            loginEmail, loginPassword, reqType
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't work because i was trying to access another route /home instead of /.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is ....on your Post requst result you can store the accessToken in localStorage

```
const result = await fetch('/',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            loginEmail, loginPassword, reqType
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json()).then(({accessToken})=>{
 
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)

});
```

then retrieve it in all of your requests

```
const anotherRequst = await fetch('/anything',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`  // get it from localStorage
        },
        body: ... /// anything 
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

that's the simplest way

... for more advanced techniques, try to use Axios

and you can simply set the default authorization header in all your requsts

```
axios.defaults.authorization = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
```

then any request you make will have the accessToken in its header

```
Axios.post(....)
Axios.get(...)
....
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I will give it a try.

Comment: @LongNguyen if it helps you, please don't forget to upvote it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'Authorization' headers within your request just like this

```
const result = await fetch('/',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        loginEmail, loginPassword, reqType
    })
}).then((res) => res.json());
```

Or if you're dealing with a big project and you have to send the token with every request then you can use Axios which allows you to add common headers with every request using only one line

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
```

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios